# Python 3 print style

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I found the following code on Stackoverflow for formatting text in Python.
(I'm running Python 3 on a Raspberry Pi.)

```
class style:
   PURPLE = '\033[95m'
   CYAN = '\033[96m'
   DARKCYAN = '\033[36m'
   BLUE = '\033[94m'
   GREEN = '\033[92m'
   YELLOW = '\033[93m'
   RED = '\033[91m'
   BOLD = '\033[1m'
   UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
   END = '\033[0m'

print (style.RED + 'SenseHat Temperature' + style.END)
```

But, I get the following results:

```
[91mSenseHat Temperature[0m
```

Comment: what format you expected to print?

Comment: Not all consoles necessarily support ANSI escape codes. It looks like yours doesn't. I get similar results when printing in my REPL in IntelliJ, which doesn't support them either.

Comment: You might be able to find a solution [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=196679). I don't have enough domain knowledge though to tell.

Comment: @Reddirt Makes sense, take a look to this [comparison](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/2j9olo8up52auoc/cmd_2018-06-30_18-27-54.png) between SublimeText console, command and conemu. Now, what about if you try [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) ?

Comment: BPL - turn your comment into an answer, and I will accept it.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using a terminal capable of showing colors and the env variable TERM is set properly

On starting python as `TERM=xterm python` on a gnome-terminal shows colored text with your code

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run this under IDLE,  ANSI escape codes won't work properly there - IDLE is simulating a minimal terminal and uses some colors for it's own warning and error messages.

The code works fine here under the default lxterminal on Raspbian as well as the native (non-GUI) linux console.